# writeStream() is printing null values in batches data even i supply proper json data in kafka through writeStream()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to convert json using schema and printing values to console, but writeStream() is printing null values in all columns even i gave proper data.

data i am giving to kafka topic ..

```
{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,quantity:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}
{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,quantity:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}
{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,quantity:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}
```

Below is my scala code..

```
 val readStreamDFInd = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "IndiaStocks")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()

//readStreamDFInd.printSchema()
val readStreamDFUS = sparkSession.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("subscribe", "USStocks")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .load()

val schema = new StructType()
  .add("stock", StringType)
  .add("buy", IntegerType)
  .add("sell", IntegerType)
  .add("profit", IntegerType)
  .add("quantity", IntegerType)
  .add("loss", IntegerType)
  .add("gender", StringType)

val stocksIndia = readStreamDFInd.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as json").select(from_json($"json", schema).as("data")).select("data.*")
val stocksUSA = readStreamDFUS.selectExpr("CAST(value as STRING) as json").select(from_json($"json", schema).as("data")).select("data.*")
stocksIndia.printSchema() stocksUSA.writeStream
  .format("console")
  .outputMode("append").trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime("5 seconds"))
  .start()
  .awaitTermination()
```

[image: Below is the null values getting printed for all columns even though i provide proper data]

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine as you can also see in the [book](https://books.google.de/books?id=8JlGDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA393&lpg=PA393&dq=spark%20selectExpr(%22CAST(value%20as%20STRING)%20as%20json%22).select(from_json&source=bl&ots=YXcyAKkL-M&sig=ACfU3U2p2JMa3dY9DOL-cs3MZBFkHN5XpA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwibp6Gwqv7oAhUxxosKHeixDkoQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=spark%20selectExpr(%22CAST(value%20as%20STRING)%20as%20json%22).select(from_json&f=false).

Looking at the documentation of the `from_json` function the `null` values are created because the string is unparseable.

=> You are missing the quotations around the `quantity` field in your json string.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your kafka data, **quantity** column should be in quotes. Please check below.

{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,**"quantity"**:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}
{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,**"quantity"**:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}
{"stock":"SEE","buy":12,"sell":15,"profit":3,**"quantity"**:27,"loss":0,"gender":"M"}